# Matching a negative integer or negative floating point number

Tags: bash, numeric

Is this the way to match a negative integer or a negative floating point number ?

```
[[ "$1" =~ [^-[0-9]*([.]*[0-9]*)$] ]]
```

I want to account for the following sets of numbers.

```
-0.0000000000667
-.0000000000667
-67
-67.0000000000667
```

One can only check for the `-` sign at the beginning, but I want to check for floating point validity as well.  Customarily, the numeric value is the result of a computation using `bc`.

An way that was suggested is to use `bc` for checking negative condition.

Have introduced a function

```
ngnum ()
{
  echo "$1 < 0" | bc -l
}
```

How can I introduce the checking in an bash `if` statement.

```
if (( $1 >= 0 )); then
  inear=$( echo "($1 + 0.5) / 1" | bc )
elif (( $1 < 0 )); then
  inear=$( echo "($1 - 0.5) / 1" | bc )
fi
```

Comment: Why do you have `[]` around the whole regular expression?

Comment: You clearly know that `[]` is used for making character sets like `[0-9]`, not for grouping. So what do you think the outer `[]` does?

Comment: You are right. Does `"$1" =~ ^-[0-9]*([.]*[0-9]*)$` cover all situations ?

Comment: An integer *is* a floating point number.

Comment: `"$1" =~ ^-([0-9]+\.)?[0-9]+$` also should work...

Comment: But why do you want to validate the output of bc?

Comment: Because the number could be user defined.  You are correct on the lack of need to scrutinise results emanating from `bc`.

Comment: How about using `bc` itself? `for n in -0.0000000000667 -.0000000000667 -67 -67.0000000000667; do [ $(echo "scale=20; $n < 0" | bc -l) -eq 1 ] ; echo $? ; done`

Comment: I like the idea of using `bc`.

Comment: @Han: Your regex would accept the number `-..`, which is not a number at all.

Comment: @User123 : May I suggest that you post your regexp as answer?

Answer (score 0):

Using `bc` itself and using `-l` option to load math library

```
#!/bin/bash

for n in 0.1 3 -0.0000000000667 -.0000000000987 -67 -67.0000000000667 -1.2E-8 0; do
    if [ $(echo "$n < 0" | bc -l) -eq 1 ] ; then
        printf  "%+17.13f : %s\n" "$n" "negative"
    else
        printf "%+17.13f : %s\n" "$n" "positive or zero"
    fi
done
```

Result:

```
 +0.1000000000000 : positive or zero
 +3.0000000000000 : positive or zero
 -0.0000000000667 : negative
 -0.0000000000987 : negative
-67.0000000000000 : negative
-67.0000000000667 : negative
 -0.0000000120000 : negative
 +0.0000000000000 : positive or zero
```

Or comparing to `-100`

```
for n in -0.0000000000667 -.0000000000667 -67 -67.0000000000667 -1.2E-8; do 
    [ $(echo "$n < -100" | bc -l) -eq 1 ]
    echo $?
done
```

Result:

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

Comment: I have introduced a function to check negativity as updated in the question.  What I would like to do, is to incorporate the negative function check within an `if` statement.

Comment: @han Updated the answer with `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

To match a negative integer, below regex can be used:

```
"$1" =~ ^-([0-9]+\.)?[0-9]+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
 ^-         :: Any number starting with "-"
([0-9]+\.)? :: To capture zero or more digit(s) to the left of a decimal point '.'
[0-9]+$     :: Any number of digits until the end
```